# Is it ever possible for an continental plate to subduct under an oceanic plate?

Tags: geology, plate-tectonics, subduction

It is well known that oceanic plates subduct under continental plates. This may be attributed to the plate's age and density, plus the water on top of it.
So I was wondering if it is ever possible for a continental plate to subduct under an oceanic plate, perhaps if the oceanic plate is covered with shallow water? I've tried to search up on this question on many search engines and sites but to no avail. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Water weight doesn't matter than much for subduction. The main effect is indirect by alteration of dense rocks like mantle rocks to less dense rocks such as serpentinites. In that case you can have mantle rocks being "obducted" as ophiolites.

Comment: But water can play a role in the pressure that has some effect on which plate subducts. Somebody answer plz!

Comment: Yes, but if you're considering that addition of water to an oceanic plate makes it less dense by average, once you start subducting the continental plate then it becomes submerged as well, and by average loses density. Maybe [ophiolites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ophiolite) can be the thing you're looking for? It's the reverse, oceanic plates being "obducted" upwards. Also check the concept of [delamination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delamination_(geology)), which is the sinking of lower continental plates into the mantle.

Comment: No. I don't think its what I am actually looking for. So, hmm I think I can explain it in a different way, lets take a simple continental oceanic subduction zone as a scenario. So, now, lets "pause" time, and turn the continental plate into oceanic, vice versa. Will the subduction continue?

Comment: Why did you get suspended?

Comment: This question makes me think of Europa.

Comment: @Muze "voting irregularities"(i.e. creating a multi). I did it to answer my unanswered questions that I found the answer to, but apparently this wasn't allowed. Oh well :P.  I believe Europa is geologically active, so I assume I know why this question has a faint connection to Europa :) lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not possible because the continental crust's density is lower.
Conversely, [oceanic plates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oceanic_crust) can subduce under continental ones because they are heavier. This is because [continental crusts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continental_crust) are formed by [granites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granite) and sedimentary materials. Their density rounds $2,7g/cm^3$, granites ones, while oceanic crust rounds $3g/cm^3$, [basalts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basalt) and [gabbros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabbro) ones.
Oceanic plates start to subduce at a certain age. Presently there are not pre-Jurassic oceanic plates that do it. This is related with the stack of hidrated sediments over the igneous materials.

An exception to this are [ophiolites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ophiolite), where oceanic plate obduce continental one. This is not happening presently at any place on Earth, but there are fossilized examples as [Semail Ophiolite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semail_Ophiolite) at Oman.

Comment: That you very much. I waited a LONG LONG time lol :) +1. BTW I think there is a typo in the first sentence. I'll fix.

Comment: You are welcome. I made a review of unasnwered questions. My english is poor so if there is any mistake in my speach feel free to edit it.